# Bootstrap dropdown menu odd behavior on menu bar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, navbar

I'm trying to include a dropdown menu in my website menu, it works fine, but when I click in it all the menu bar gets disordered. The dropdown menu moves the header down, changing the design. I have tried to upload a pic, but the website didn't let me to.

Basically the problem is that when we click on the dropdown menu, it enlarges the menu bar changing the design, the dropdown menu doesn't unfold over the other elements.
Hope you can help to me thanks a lot for your support.

```
    <header id="header" role="banner">
      <div class="container">
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-default">
          <div class="navbar-heade">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".bs-navbar-collapse"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="../../index.html"></a> </div>
            <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li class="active"><a href="#main-slider"><i class="icon-home"></i></a></li>
                  <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Search your Place</a></li>
                  <li><a href="logout">Public your Place</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Sign Up</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModallogin">Log In</a></li>

                  <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                      <i class="icon-user"></i> Prueba
                      <i class="icon-caret-down"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">My Account</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a tabindex="-1" class="visible-phone" href="#">Opciones</a></li>
                      <li class="divider visible-phone"></li>
                      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="logout"><i class="icon-off"></i> Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
```

I have tried this in bootstrap.css

```
    .dropdown-menu {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 9999;

    }
    .navbar-default {
      background: #fff;
      border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
      border: 0;
      padding: 0;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
      -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
      box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
      overflow: hidden;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the two solution

**1)**

The css code which you trying above is not all required.. it works fine without that also.. here is the demo for that    http://jsfiddle.net/adarshkr/k7e7w1e6/

**2)**

Correction required in your **CSS**

```
.dropdown-menu {
      position: absolute; /* it should not relative */
      z-index: 9999;

    }
    .navbar-default {
      background: #fff;
      border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
      border: 0;
      padding: 0;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
      -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
      box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
      /* overflow: hidden;*/  /*comment of this line */
}
```

here is the link for this correction

http://jsfiddle.net/adarshkr/mo86gv1o/